Are these two Hölder-type inequalities valid?
Hereinafter, we use $p$-norm ($p\geqslant1$) in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, which is given as $\|x\|_p=(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p)^{1/p}$.
As we know that, the following inequality holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $1/p+1/q=1$ with $p,q\geqslant1$:
\begin{equation}
\|x\|_2^2\leqslant\|x\|_p\|x\|_q,
\end{equation}
which can be obtained directly from the standard Hölder's inequality.
Now let us turn to two more general inequalities:
\begin{equation}
\|x\|_2\|y\|_2
\leqslant\max\{\|x\|_p\|y\|_q, \|x\|_q\|y\|_p\}.\tag{1}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\|x\|_2\|y\|_2
\leqslant\frac{\|x\|_p\|y\|_q+\|x\|_q\|y\|_p}{2}.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
I have tested them many times with MATLAB, and there were no counterexamples. While I am unable to give a rigorous mathematical proof, I guess both are valid.
Any proof or answer will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

From
$$
\|x\|_2 \le \sqrt{\|x\|_p \|x\|_q} 
$$
for all $x$ and the inequality between the geometric and arithmetic mean ($\sqrt{ab} \le (a+b)/2$) we get
$$\begin{align} 
\|x\|_2\|y\|_2 &\le \sqrt{\|x\|_p \|x\|_q\|y\|_p \|y\|_q} \\&= \sqrt{(\|x\|_p \|y\|_q)( \|x\|_q\|y\|_p)} \\&\le \frac{\|x\|_p \|y\|_q + \|x\|_q\|y\|_p}{2}\\
&\le \frac{\max\{\|x\|_p \|y\|_q,\|x\|_q\|y\|_p\}+\max\{\|x\|_p \|y\|_q,\|x\|_q\|y\|_p\}}{2} \\&= \max\{\|x\|_p \|y\|_q,\|x\|_q\|y\|_p\}.\end{align} 
$$

Looks like I was just one shot away. You are sharp. Thanks for your quick answer!

Glad I could help.
